# Haskell custom data types

Tags: haskell, hash, types

I have struggled with this for hours, and I cannot figure it out.

```
module Main where
import Data.List
import Data.Function

type Raw = (String, String)

icards = [("the", "le"),("savage", "violent"),("work", "travail"),("wild", "sauvage"),
("chance", "occasion"),("than a", "qu'un"),("expensive.", "cher."),("saves", "en 
vaut"),("time", "temps"),("in", "<`a>"), ("worse", "pire"),("{", "{"),("A", "Un"),
("stitch", "point"),("crime;", "crime,"),("a", "une"),("nine.", "cent."),("It's", 
"C'est"),("all","tout"),("rare", "rare"),("you", "vous"),("Abandon","Abandonnez"),
("stash", "planquer"),("Everything", "Tout!ce!qui!est"),("who enter.", "qui entrez."),
("Zazie", "Zazie"),("is", "est"),("cat", "chat"),("it's", "c'est"),("raisin", "raisin 
sec"),("hope,", "espoir,"),("mistake.", "faute."),("luck", "chance"),("blueberry", 
"myrtille"),("I!took", "J'ai pris"),("that", "qui"),("a!chance.", "des risques."),
("drink", "boisson"),("Live", "Vivre"),("regrets.", "regrets."),("stone", "pierre"),
("broke", "a fait d<e'>border"),("without", "sans"),("The!straw", "La goutte d'eau"),
("camel's!back.", "vase.")]


data Entry = Entry {wrd, def :: String, len :: Int, phr :: Bool}
        deriving Show

-- English-to-French, hash-table section

entries :: [Entry]
entries = map (\(x, y) -> Entry x y (length x) (' ' `elem` x)) icards

type Run = [Entry]

maxl = maximum [len e | e <- entries]

runs :: [Run]
runs = f 0 $ groupBy ((==) `on` len) $ sortBy (compare `on` len) entries
  where f _ [] = []
        f i (r @ (Entry {len = l} : _) : rs) | i == l = r  : f (i + 1) rs
        f i                              rs           = [] : f (i + 1) rs

type Word = String

search' :: Word -> [Entry] -> String
search' searchWord subList 
search' _ [] = "unknown"
search' ([def x | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord])==[] = "no match"
search' = [def x | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord]

--search' searchWord subList = (def | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord)
--search' searchWord subList = [def x::String | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord]
--search' searchWord [subList] = [def | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord]
--search' searchWord subList = [def | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord]
--search' searchWord subList = [def x | x <- subList,  (wrd x) == searchWord]
--search' searchWord subList = [x->def | x <- subList,  (x->wrd) == searchWord]

search :: [Run] -> Word -> String
search runList searchWord = search' searchWord $ runList!!wrdLen
                     where wrdLen = (length searchWord)
```

I need help with the search' function.  GHCi will tell me that expected type is char... and actual type is Entry-> String.

But I expected type to be the string.  I don't know why it thinks I want just a char.

In general here is what I expect:
Send a `[Run]` and a Word to Search, where `[Run] = [[Entries]]` and `Word = String`

the `[Run]` should be formatted so all of the Entries in `[Run]!!0` are length 0, `[Run]!!1` are length 1 etc.

So, function search should check the length of the sent Word, then call search' and send it the subList associated to the list of entries that have the same length as the word.

Once inside search' I just want to do a linear search of the list for the `wrd == Word`, then return the def of that word.

any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate problems:

1. You should apply `def` to an `Entry` if you want a `String`. So, the definition of `search'` should look like this:

```
search' searchWord subList = [def x | x <- subList, wrd x == searchWord]
```

2. It is not obvious, a priori, that searching will always find exactly one match. There may be no matches, or many matches. (I understand that you may expect that the data you provide will result in exactly one match, but that kind of reasoning is a bit beyond what can be done both efficiently and statically.) So, your `search'` and `search` functions should return lists. The type signatures should look like this:

```
search' :: Word -> [Entry] -> [String]
search :: [Run] -> Word -> [String]
```

...and, indeed, if you leave the type signatures off, GHC will infer exactly those types (up to type synonyms).

edit: To address the updated question, you probably want something like this:

```
search' searchWord subList = case [def x | x <- subList, wrd x == searchWord] of
    [] -> "no match"
    (match:_) -> match
```

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) has a section about pattern matching if you want to know more. It also has a section on [lists and list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out), and is generally just a good tutorial.

However, I strongly advise against writing `search'` this way: it's a bit dishonest! (For example, as the caller of `search'`, how can I differentiate between the result 'the search succeeded, and the translation is "no match"' and the result 'the search failed'?)

Comment: Why do i want them to return [String]... if i only want one exact match? And, how do i add conditions for no matches in the code?  My understanding is that once Haskell finds the first match it should stop what is doing and return... so i dont think i need to worry about multiple matches?

Comment: One question at a time. 1. If you want one exact match, you must handle the other cases yourself. Use a `case` statement like `case matches of [] -> "a string you want to return when there are no matches"; (match:_) -> match`. 2. You do not need to add any additional code to return an empty list when there are no matches; it already does that. 3. Your understanding is incorrect. You might want to review the section on list comprehensions in whatever tutorial you like best.

Comment: i have no idea how to use a `case` statement. i will look for some examples.  And review list comprehensions.

Comment: See new search' function above.  this says 'parse error in pattern' for the "no match" part

Comment: @Special--k Okay, I've updated the answer. However, in the future, you should start a new question for each distinct problem you are trying to solve; otherwise, the questions and answers can get confusingly out of synch.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, let's see. You have a list of stuff, `[a]`. You have some criteria for determining whether or not the search succeeded, `a -> Bool`. And you want to perform the search on the list, returning a value of the element type `a`. Stop...Hoogle time! [Hoogling `[a] -> (a -> Bool) -> a`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+a), the top hit is `find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a`. The only catch is that it returns a `Maybe a`: it will either find `Just something` or `Nothing`. I'd say this is an appropriate upgrade for your `search` function.

```
search :: [Run] -> Word -> Maybe Entry
search runList searchWord = find (\x -> wrd x == searchWord) $ runList!!wrdLen
  where wrdLen = (length searchWord)
```

Since we've changed the contract for `search` to produce a `Maybe Entry` instead of a simple `String`, if you were using it like this before:

```
doStuff (search runList searchWord)
```

You will now have to take into account the possibility of the search failing.

```
case search runList searchWord of
  Just foundWord -> doStuff (def foundWord)
  Nothing        -> doSomethingElse
```

If you are absolutely sure that the search will never fail, you can unwrap it with `fromJust`

```
doStuff (fromJust $ def $ search runList searchWord)
```

Although `fromJust` is generally discouraged.

---

Now, one other thing. You said you wanted to return only the `def`, not the entire `Entry`. As you should know, we can use `def :: Entry -> String` as a field accessor to extract the `def` out of an `Entry`. But how do we apply this to a `Maybe Entry`?

Stop...Hoogle time! We have a value, `v :: Maybe a`. We have a function that works on plain old `a` values, `f :: a -> b`. We want to somehow apply `f` to `v`, yielding a result of type `b`. [Hoogling `Maybe a -> (a -> b) -> b`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+b), I see two good options.

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe n _ Nothing = n
maybe _ f (Just x) = f x
```

The `maybe` function takes a function and a maybe value, and also a *default*. If the maybe value turns out to be `Nothing`, it just uses the default. Otherwise, it uses the function `f` on the value inside of the `Just` constructor.

```
search :: [Run] -> Word -> String
search runList searchWord = search' (\x -> wrd x == searchWord) $ runList!!wrdLen
  where wrdLen = (length searchWord)

search' :: (Entry -> Bool) -> [Entry] -> String
search' f es = maybe "not found" def $ find f es
-- or eta reduce: search' = maybe "not found" def . find
```

This solution is OK, but I prefer the next one better.

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

If you are not familiar with functors, I highly recommend [Learn you a Haskell > the Functor typeclass](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass). Maybe is a functor, which means we can use `fmap` on maybe values.

```
search' :: (Entry -> Bool) -> [Entry] -> Maybe String
search' f es = fmap def $ find f es
```